# MySQL Where In comparisons - string vs. integer. - getting mixed up

Tags: mysql

I am having issues with the `where in` query, where the comparison is returning totally incorrect rows. I know this is due to integer vs. string comparisons but it feels very wrong. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

```sql
select * from `documents` where `id` in ('2f9a548e-701b-4ecc-b8e8-06869a1a1081')
```

returns...

```
| id | uuid                                 |
|----|--------------------------------------|
|  2 | 7a0c9bcd-3ca6-4780-8645-8cbe05652c5e |
```

and

```sql
select * from `documents` where `uuid` in (1)
```

returns...

```
| id    | uuid                                 |
|-------|--------------------------------------|
| 10098 | 001ad091-da95-4b25-9ecb-39bac5466782 |
```

Comment: 'Is there any way to prevent this from happening?' - no there isn't it's a 'feature'

Comment: The actual problem is that you are passing totally wrong values in a query. Fix your program and this won't be an issue.

Comment: I realise this is an app issue, but I want to be able to protect from a developer from inputting the wrong type and still getting a result that could be mistaken as the code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to disable the type juggling that MySQL does in comparisons between values. The only way to avoid it is by ensuring both values are of the same type to begin with.

In the first case you can cast `id` as `CHAR` to avoid the problem:

```
select * 
from `documents` 
where cast(`id` as char) in ('2f9a548e-701b-4ecc-b8e8-06869a1a1081')
```

In the second case you just need the values in the `in` expression to be strings, not integers:

```
select * 
from `documents` 
where `uuid` in ('1')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=afd70b503b159d58dd37a8c04adfd101)